# works when gameScene is loaded first , but play for half a sec and immediately stops (no error) when loaded by another scene, why ?

Tags: ios, swift, skscene, skaudionode

in the gameScene.swift: 
declaration:

```
var backgroundMusic: SKAudioNode!
```

in didMoveToView:

```
  if let musicURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Jalandhar", withExtension: "mp3") {
            backgroundMusic = SKAudioNode(URL: musicURL)
             addChild(backgroundMusic)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ended up using AVAudioPlayer to workaround it , code may be useful: 
declare as property :

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
```

then in a function :

```
 let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("musicfile", ofType: "mp3")
        let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath!)
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, fileTypeHint: nil)
            audioPlayer.play()        }
        catch {
            print("music error")
        }
```